# Where is the file data sent with jQueryFileUpload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm working on file uploads and I wanted a plugin that could let users easily update their profile pictures, or avatars, with one click. Someone recommended jQueryFileUpload by blueimp. I have the view part of it setup (a link which, when clicked, opens a filechooser dialog), but I'm having problems receiving the file data. Fiddler shows the file data being posted to the url I want, but I can't seem to find where the data of the file I selected is being stored. Using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

shows only one parameter.

My javascript is the following:

```
$(".hoverAction").on('click', function(e) {
            $(".fileInput:first").fileupload({
                url: "/user/update",
                singleFileUploads: true,
                formData: {
                    type: "avatar"
                },
                add: function(e, data)  {
                    var goUpload = true;
                    var uploadFile = data.files[0];
                    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
                        common.notifyError('You must select an image file only');
                        goUpload = false;
                    }
                    if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
                        common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
                        goUpload = false;
                    }
                    if (goUpload == true) {
                        data.submit();
                    }
                }
            });

            $(".fileInput:first").click();
```

And my POST handler is the following:

```
function updateAction() {
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        switch($type)   {
            case "avatar":
                print_r($_POST); // returns only the type param
                break;
            case "cover":
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```

Comment: File uploads are found in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: @Barmar That's a step in the right direction, but in Fiddler I see the actual file data. Where is that being stored?

Comment: It's being stored in a temporary file on the server, and `$_FILES` contains the name of the temporary file. Just like if you'd done a normal upload form instead of AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar Ohhh. I thought the plugin was just reading the file and posting its data to my handler. I didn't think it was uploading it to a temp location. Alright, that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the documentation on https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup on how to build the back end. The plugin archives contain a basic PHP example which you can use as a starting point.